# HTML and CSS popup card

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am creating a Web Browser with Electron and I need help creating a popup card. I search everywhere for something like this, but I cannot find anything.

What I need create popups that are like the provided images. Something like a chrome extension popup frame (preferably the chrome connection popup), these will be used to create connection popups, extensions popups, etc.

#### Chrome connection popup

[image: Chrome Connection Popup]

#### Visual Studio Code editor popup

[image: Visual Studio Code Popup]

[Chrome Extension popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ukr1.png)

Comment: You mean a custom hover tooltip (modal) element?

Comment: I mean, kind of. I need something that displays over all of the elements and your can display interactive content in. like a chrome extension frame.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a modal popup. This can be a div that is hidden by default, but shows when you click or hover over another element.

It needs to have `absolute` positioning and you will need to update the `top` and `left` style properties based on the `event` properties `clientY` and `clientX` respectivly.

```js
const modalTooltip = document.querySelector('#modal-tooltip');

const showModal = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
  Object.assign(modalTooltip.style, { top: `${clientY}px`, left: `${clientX}px` });
  modalTooltip.classList.add('tooltip-visible');
};

const hideModal = () => {
  modalTooltip.classList.remove('tooltip-visible');
};

document.querySelector('.site-info').addEventListener('click', showModal);
modalTooltip.querySelector('.tooltip-close').addEventListener('click', hideModal);
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  color: #DDD;
}

.demo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.demo-help {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.site-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background: #666;
  border: thin solid #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.site-info {
  color: #DDD;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #4E4C46;
  color: #EEE;
  border: thin solid #222;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.tooltip.tooltip-visible {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  align-items: top;
}

.tooltip-close {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip-close:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}

.tooltip-top, .tooltip-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.tooltip-top {
  flex: 1;
}

.tooltip-bottom {
  border-top: thin solid #999896;
}

.tooltip-title {
  color: #86CB81;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  flex: 1;
}

.tooltip-content {
  flex: 1;
}

.tooltip a,
.tooltip a:active,
.tooltip a:hover {
  color: #9CAB83;
}

.tooltip-options {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0.667em;
}

.tooltip-options .fas {
  color: #70706f;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip-option-flag {
  color: #999896;
}

#modal-tooltip {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="demo">
  <div class="site-info">
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="demo-help">&larr; Click Me!</div>
</div>

<div class="tooltip" id="modal-tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip-top">
    <div class="tooltip-header">
      <div class="tooltip-title">Connection is secure</div>
      <div class="fas fa-times tooltip-close"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip-content">
      Your information (for example, passwords or credit card numbers) is private when it is sent to this site. <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip-bottom">
    <div class="tooltip-options">
    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i>
      Certificate
      <span class="tooltip-option-flag">(Valid)</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-palette" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Cookies
      <span class="tooltip-option-flag">(16 in use)</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Site settings
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question and your help. This is exactly what I am looking for, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### here is a sample code for POP UP CARD

---

**TEST SNIPPET CODE**

---

1. save HTML code as index.html
2. save CSS code as style.css

**note- CSS file name should be matched with what you used in html***

**i.e. *link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"**

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
a,
a:link {
  font-family: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container:target {
  display: flex;
}
.modal {
  width: 60rem;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #009FFF, #ec2F4B);
  box-shadow: .4rem .4rem 2.4rem .2rem hsla(236, 50%, 50%, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.details {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .4);
}
.title {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
}
.description {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-style: italic;
}
.txt {
  padding: 0 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2;
}
.txt::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 18rem;
  height: 18rem;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .2);
  border-radius: 100rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.btn {
  padding: 1rem 1.6rem;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .4);
  border-radius: 100rem;
  color: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  transition: .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .6);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-.2rem);
          transform: translateY(-.2rem);
}
.link-1 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #009FFF, #ec2F4B);
  box-shadow: .4rem .4rem 2.4rem .2rem hsla(236, 50%, 50%, 0.3);
  border-radius: 100rem;
  padding: 1.4rem 3.2rem;
  transition: .2s;
}
.link-1:hover,
.link-1:focus {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-.2rem);
          transform: translateY(-.2rem);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4.4rem .2rem hsla(236, 50%, 50%, 0.4);
}
.link-2 {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .4);
  border-radius: 100rem;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  transition: .2s;
}
.link-2::before {
  content: '×';
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-.1rem);
          transform: translateY(-.1rem);
}
.link-2:hover,
.link-2:focus {
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .6);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-.2rem);
          transform: translateY(-.2rem);
}


----------
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--code by alok shukla-->
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>pop up card</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 
 <a href="#modal-opened" class="link-1" id="modal-closed">open pop up card</a>
 
<div class="container" id="modal-opened">
  <div class="modal">
 
    <div class="details">
      <h1 class="title">Your Title</h1>
      <p class="description">Slogan will be here at this place.</p>
    </div>
 
    <p class="txt">some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz 
        some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz some xyz </p>
 
    <button class="btn">Button &rarr;</button>
 
    <a href="#modal-closed" class="link-2"></a>
 
  </div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and taking your time to answer, this could be helpful. I am looking for a tool tip style popover